Website displaying differently on Instagrams internal browser
I made a website where I basically hide and correspondingly show an element on mobile screen sizes.
This seems to work just fine with any browser and size but somehow Instagram apparently renders it very differently... (see attached screenshots). It basically shows both elements. The one I want to hide and the one I want to show. (You can test the site yourself on https://cato-sports.com/events/berlin-marathon-2024)
Here is how it should look:iPhone Screenshot showing the correct layout of the site
Here is how it looks opened in the Instagram App:enter image description here
Here's a dulled down snippet for this subpage:


.event-container-full {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.event-header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: black;
}

.event-image-container {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.event-header-img {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 70%;
}

.event-infobox {
  grid-column: 3 / span 7;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
}

.event-form {
  position: absolute;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  width: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
  z-index: -1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .event-form {
    display: flex;
    position: relative !important;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    translate: unset;
    justify-self: end;
    left: unset;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  .event-infobox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .event-container-full {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: relative !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: auto;
  }
  .form-container-m {
    display: block !important;
    padding: 1rem !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .form-container {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .event-header {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
<div class="event-container-full">

  <div class="event-header">
    <img src="https://cato-sports.com/media/pages/events/berlin-marathon-2024/b6920f0b41-1726914650/foto-24-small.jpeg" class="event-header-img">
  </div>

  <section class="event-form">

    <div class="event-image-container" style="background-image: url(https://cato-sports.com/media/pages/events/berlin-marathon-2024/b6920f0b41-1726914650/foto-24-small.jpeg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position: center;">
      <!-- <img src="https://cato-sports.com/media/pages/events/berlin-marathon-2024/b6920f0b41-1726914650/foto-24-small.jpeg" class="event-image-card"> -->
    </div>
    <div class="event-infobox">
      <mark class="event-page-title">Marathon Post Race Zone</mark>
      <mark class="event-page-location">Berlin</mark>
      <div class="event-page-time">
        29.09.2024 — 2:00 pm</time>
      </div>
      <hr class="eventcard-ruler">
      <p class="event-text">
        Join us for our Post Race Community Zone @LAP Coffee (Uhlandstra&szlig;e 30) for free coffee &amp; pastries, live tunes &amp; exclusive access to our new performance line. The first 30 people showing up will receive a special gift. You don&#039;t need
        to run the Marathon to join! </p>

      <p class="event-guests">19 Guests already attending</p>

      <div class="form-container">

        <form action="https://cato-sports.com/forms/marathon-post-race-zone-berlin" class="form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" hx-post="https://cato-sports.com/forms/marathon-post-race-zone-berlin" hx-swap="outerHTML show:top" hx-vals="{&quot;dreamform:page&quot;:&quot;78PYElO/+wPRZVpaVP2+Cqw9g367wbu6yz53iztMs31YEjg5hzgXg8v6+znHFGzZLXhbNuDxzSOuJwSS8B7GWKmZczNjAB6Rf4rMpbFhNOU=&quot;,&quot;dreamform:attr&quot;:&quot;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&quot;}"
          id="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
          <div class="form-error" data-error></div>
          <div class="form-row" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);">
            <div class="form-column" style="grid-column-start: span 6;">

              <div class="form-field">

                <label class="form-label" for="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/2c20deaa-6d7d-47b3-9233-9cdedc60ad6c">
                                        <span>First Name</span>
                                        <em>*</em>
                                    </label>

                <input class="form-input" id="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/2c20deaa-6d7d-47b3-9233-9cdedc60ad6c" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required type="text">

                <span class="form-error" data-error="firstname"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-column" style="grid-column-start: span 6;">

              <div class="form-field">

                <label class="form-label" for="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/dab4ef21-9480-4799-85dc-2d8367fce737">
                                        <span>Last Name</span>
                                        <em>*</em>
                                    </label>

                <input class="form-input" id="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/dab4ef21-9480-4799-85dc-2d8367fce737" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required type="text">

                <span class="form-error" data-error="lastname"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);">
            <div class="form-column" style="grid-column-start: span 12;">

              <div class="form-field">

                <label class="form-label" for="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/e6cd37c1-28af-44a0-afa4-f0bfb12efb04">
                                        <span>Email</span>
                                        <em>*</em>
                                    </label>

                <input class="form-input" id="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/e6cd37c1-28af-44a0-afa4-f0bfb12efb04" name="useremail" placeholder="Email" required type="email">

                <span class="form-error" data-error="useremail"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);">
            <div class="form-column" style="grid-column-start: span 12;">

              <input type="text" style="position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;padding:0;margin:-1px;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(0,0,0,0);white-space:nowrap;border-width:0;" aria-hidden tabindex="-1" name="website">
              <div class="form-field">

                <button class="form-btn" hx-disabled-elt="this" type="submit">
                                        RSVP</button>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

  </section>

</div>

<div class="form-container-m">

  <form action="https://cato-sports.com/forms/marathon-post-race-zone-berlin" class="form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" hx-post="https://cato-sports.com/forms/marathon-post-race-zone-berlin" hx-swap="outerHTML show:top" hx-vals="{&quot;dreamform:page&quot;:&quot;h80pQ8H6sT9SlPUojuT4IXYdEMFVXCunyc9clapd+gxIN3qsOACUknhxQq8hwLJyxCYuLvwjbniiVqOnWGVoEasTPOF3Cto89d69bErRMec=&quot;,&quot;dreamform:attr&quot;:&quot;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&quot;}"
    id="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-error" data-error></div>
    <div class="form-row" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);">
      <div class="form-column" style="grid-column-start: span 6;">

        <div class="form-field">

          <label class="form-label" for="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/2c20deaa-6d7d-47b3-9233-9cdedc60ad6c">
                            <span>First Name</span>
                            <em>*</em>
                        </label>

          <input class="form-input" id="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/2c20deaa-6d7d-47b3-9233-9cdedc60ad6c" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required type="text">

          <span class="form-error" data-error="firstname"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-column" style="grid-column-start: span 6;">

        <div class="form-field">

          <label class="form-label" for="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/dab4ef21-9480-4799-85dc-2d8367fce737">
                            <span>Last Name</span>
                            <em>*</em>
                        </label>

          <input class="form-input" id="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/dab4ef21-9480-4799-85dc-2d8367fce737" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required type="text">

          <span class="form-error" data-error="lastname"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);">
      <div class="form-column" style="grid-column-start: span 12;">

        <div class="form-field">

          <label class="form-label" for="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/e6cd37c1-28af-44a0-afa4-f0bfb12efb04">
                            <span>Email</span>
                            <em>*</em>
                        </label>

          <input class="form-input" id="2uTWataEmJkpdwM1/e6cd37c1-28af-44a0-afa4-f0bfb12efb04" name="useremail" placeholder="Email" required type="email">

          <span class="form-error" data-error="useremail"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);">
      <div class="form-column" style="grid-column-start: span 12;">

        <input type="text" style="position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;padding:0;margin:-1px;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(0,0,0,0);white-space:nowrap;border-width:0;" aria-hidden tabindex="-1" name="website">
        <div class="form-field">

          <button class="form-btn" hx-disabled-elt="this" type="submit">
                            RSVP</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>



I hope someone here can help me out on this a little as Im scratching my head as to what makes Instagram render this differently than on any other browser / browser size... (I've already cleared cache etc...)
Thank you

Please click [edit] then the button marked [<>] and provide a [mcve] with RENDERED HTML, not PHP since this is not related to PHP (so you can also remove the tags)

@mplungjan hey there! I've added a dulled down snippet. Hope that helps! You can also always visit the actual website :) Thanks!

Try to explicitly show and hide depending on the media query. Also add the !important in case there is an overriding css in instagram web view
/* Default: Show desktop form, hide mobile form */
.form-container {
  display: block !important;
}
.form-container-m {
  display: none !important; 
}
/* Mobile: Show mobile form, hide desktop form */
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .form-container {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .form-container-m {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

